# Selenium Webdriver NoSuchElementException on python

Tags: python, html, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I am using Selenium Webdriver for python, currently on Chrome browser and I've been stuck in a kind of strange situation with this particular lib. I want to extract some info in Pipedrive(currently able to login and search for a specific lead inside the webpage, but when I try to extract a Person's name I am having this exception:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/ppbbd/PycharmProjects/fastTasks/pipeforwpp.py", line 27, in <module>
    info_box = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='widget personFields fieldsView   '][@data-state='read']")
  File "C:\Users\ppbbd\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 394, in find_element_by_xpath
    return self.find_element(by=By.XPATH, value=xpath)
  File "C:\Users\ppbbd\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 978, in find_element
    'value': value})['value']
  File "C:\Users\ppbbd\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Users\ppbbd\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//div[@class='widget personFields fieldsView   '][@data-state='read']"}
  (Session info: chrome=80.0.3987.149)
```

A snippet of the code here:(The info I want to extract is inside `info_box = ...`)

```
for i in range(0, 195):
    search_box = driver.find_element_by_name('needle')
    if data_abril.iloc[i+1, 1] == 'N/A':
        pass
    else:
        escola = int(data_abril.iloc[i+1, 1])
        search_box.send_keys(str(escola))
        time.sleep(2)
        search_box.send_keys(Keys.DOWN)
        search_box.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
        time.sleep(10)
        info_box = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='widget personFields fieldsView   '][@data-state='read']")
        # info_box_a = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='fieldsList read']")
```

I searched about this exception and one of the main causes were about dynamic pages and element's load time in the page were not all simultaneous, so I used `time.sleep(10)` just to test if it was the case but I still got the error shown above.

---

**IMPORTANT NOTE:** Here is a snippet of the html, if you look in the end of the code, the comment
 `info_box_a = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='fieldsList read']")` works fine and as you can see in the image, this particular div is inside the problematic one, so how could Selenium be unable to locate a parent but its child?
[HTML SNIPPET](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bLZdq.png)

---

**PAGE SOURCE:** I was not able to post it in here because it would bypass the 30k character limit and the sourcepage is inside a login area so even if i post the url unless you have an account on Pipedrive you won't be able to see the page source(correct me if I am wrong). Any suggestions to show another html snippet I can update the question.

---

**UPDATE:**

As you see in the link below, the specific info of a person's phone class value is `class="item read
    phoneField editable
    "` whith this much of whitespace on it, **does this interphere on finding the element?** or does `class="item read phoneField editable"` means exactly the same?

[Important HTML snippet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gxCex.png)

---

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with the below xpath where we are [normalizing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dotnet/netframework-4.0/ms256063(v%3Dvs.100)) the white spaces in the class.

```
//div[normalize-space(@class)='widget personFields fieldsView'][@data-state='read']
```

[image]

And you can update your info_box as below.

```
info_box = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[normalize-space(@class)='widget personFields fieldsView'][@data-state='read']")
```